# EF4 Selftracking Entity

Tags: ef4-code-only

I'm wokring on building dataAcess layer for my application I'm using EF4 Self tracking entities I build entities quit well now I have to seprate self entities to their files so I can use for N tiers.
So far I did follow this url
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/133689/How-to-Separate-Self-Tracking-Entities-to-Their-Ow.aspx?display=Mobile

but when I build solution it gave me error 
Error   2   The type or namespace name 'IObjectWithChangeTracker' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\test\EF4 STE\STE\STEEntities\tbl_Departments.cs  22  49  STEEntities
and more like this
any one can help
thanks